# Need those not in the table

Tags: .net, database, linq, entity

I have a problem... I have three tables: `game`, `gamelist`, and `player`. The `game` table contains games, the `gamelist` contains all the players who want to play in a game and the `player` table contains all the players.

I have made this query:

```
  var query1 = from es in gr.games
           join esh in gr.gameLists on es.id equals esh.gameID
           where es.holdID == play.holdID && esh.playerID.HasValue && esh.playerID == personID
                                    select es;
```

This query gets me all the games a player has signed up for... but how do I get all the games he hasn't signed up for? Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simple **invert the join condition**, that is select the `game` items that **are not** in the `gameLists` table.
However, since LINQ only supports [equi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Equi-join), you'll have to express it using a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) filtered with a `where` clause:

```
var results = from es in gr.games
              from esh in gr.gameLists
              where es.id != esh.gameID &&
                    esh.playerID.HasValue && esh.playerID == personID
              select es;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all games you can check what games are in that complete list that ain't excisting in the list of games that the player has signed up for. This way you extract all games that he hasn't signed up for.